# How do I put python script on path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I know this question has been asked before. I've done just about all the suggestions, but I'm still having an issue.

I have a script `file_rename_script.py` that I have made executable, and I've tested away from the path to make sure that it's working as expected, all is well. However, when I move that script to my path, I get the following:

```
/Users/Nick/bin/file_rename_script.py: line 1: import: command not found
from: can't read /var/mail/datetime
/Users/Nick/bin/file_rename_script.py: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Users/Nick/bin/file_rename_script.py: line 4: `current_directory = os.listdir(os.getcwd())'
```

Here is what the file looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os, time
from datetime import datetime

current_directory = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
files = [f for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if os.path.isfile(f)]

for file in files:
    file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)
    create_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(file)).strftime('%Y_%m_%d')
    prompt_user = "What would you like to name " + file + " to? "
    user_response = input(prompt_user)
    if user_response:
        os.rename(file, create_date + "-" + user_response.replace(" ", "_") + file_extension)
        print("Renamed your file to", create_date + "-" + user_response.replace(" ", "_") + file_extension)
        print()
    else:
        print(file, "was not changed")
        print()
```

Why is it that I can't run this when it's on my path? Also note, I've had the shebang set as `#!/usr/local/bin/python3` as well with no success.

Ideally I'd like to keep this file somewhere else, and I'd like to symlink it as an alias on my path.

What gives?

Comment: Try run `env python3` in your shell?

Comment: Do you get python prompt when you run `env python3`? What happens when you run `which python3` in the command line?

Errors indicate that shebang is not working correctly, so the shell is trying to run your python script directly as a shell script, not using python interpreter...

Comment: @GoranRakic I do get a prompt when running `env python3`, `which python3` gives me `/usr/local/bin/python3`. I agree that the shebang seems to be the culprit. However those paths are right.

Comment: Can you double check if there are no spaces or empty lines before #!? If you are using Windows, save the file without BOM.

Comment: I did just notice that the env was at a different path. I updated, but still see same issue. Could it be because they were both installed via `brew`? I've doubled checked, there is no whitespace before.

Comment: If you can get Python prompt by running `/usr/bin/env python3` then everything is fine with env and python. Try running `head -1 /Users/Nick/bin/file_rename_script.py | od -cx` and paste the output here.

Comment: `0000000   i   m   p   o   r   t       o   s   ,       t   i   m   e  \n
           6d69    6f70    7472    6f20    2c73    7420    6d69    0a65
0000020`

Comment: This output shows that /Users/Nick/bin/file_rename_script.py is missing the first line. The first line of this script is not a shebang, but "import os..."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98297/discussion-between-goran-rakic-and-ndland).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errors indicate that she-bang is not working, and the shell is trying to run your python code (/Users/Nick/bin/file_rename_script.py) directly as a shell script, not using a python interpreter...

1. First verify that you get Python prompt if you run `/usr/bin/env python3`. If not, try to look for python3 by running `which python3`
2. Second, double check that there are no spaces or empty lines before the she-bang line `#!`. If you are creating file on Windows, save the file without BOM (this is an invisible character at the beginning of a file). Line must end with a new line character (`\n`). You can run `head` and `od` to print bytes (characters) from the first line of the file:

   head -1 /Users/Nick/bin/file_rename_script.py | od -cx

It should print (The first character is `#`, and the last one is `\n`):

```
0000000   #   !   /   u   s   r   /   b   i   n   /   e   n   v       p
           2123    752f    7273    622f    6e69    652f    766e    7020
0000020   y   t   h   o   n   3  \n
           7479    6f68    336e    000a
0000027
```

Comment: the error indicates that the shebang is absent (that is confirmed by the direct inspection of the file (provided in [the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347486/how-do-i-put-python-script-on-path#comment56436970_34347486))). Wrong shebang such as having a Windows newline (`b'\r\n'`) leads to ["No such file or directory" error](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454074/23044) while OP's error indicates that the python script is run as a shell script.

Comment: I made the mistake of not double checking which file I was putting on the path. As it turns out. I put the wrong file on the path.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the python exe location to environment path if you use windows or linux.

For widows and linux
Add the python exexutable path variable to path

If you use virtual env,please activate the virrual env first.add the virtual env python package path.such as

!#env python
Script must be add into upper directory of env
Must run the env call env/Scripts/activate if you use virtual env
Directory structure should be

App

-- env

-- yourscript.py

Install the virtual env by pip.